# How can I set the class for an element using jQuery? Don't want to add/remove classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to set the class for an element in my page. With plain JavaScript, I would write something like:

```
document.getElementById('foo').className = "my_class";
```

This just sets the class, which is exactly what I want. But I'm using jQuery on my page and so would like to do this in a "jQuery way", since it seems weird to mix the old style and the jQuery style. But jQuery apparently only allows you use addClass() or removeClass(), like so:

```
$('#foo').addClass("my_class");
```

The problem is that it merely adds a class to the element, it does not replace the currently existing class. Does this mean I have to keep track of the old class and do a removeClass() first? Is there no way to tell jQuery to replace the current class no matter what it is and just replace it with a new one?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To remove all classes from an element:

```
$('#foo').removeClass();
```

Specifying no arguments to removeClass removes all the classes. So your solution would be:

```
$('#foo').removeClass().addClass('my_class');
```

Comment: If you really want to use the "class" functions then chain your operations, no need to reinstanciate a new `$('#foo')` object: `$('#foo').removeClass().addClass('my_class');` -1 for not optimized and not really answering the question (this solution is already explained in the question)

Comment: Actually, I thought he did answer my question quite well: The removeClass() function was the key that I didn't know about. So, I thought this was a good answer.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I thought you already knew `removeClass()` would remove any existing class since you were litteraly typing it like this in your question ;-) Anyway, the optimization part is important, you have to use methods chaining whenever possible.

Comment: Yes, or else your doing two lookups in the DOM.

Answer (score 10):

Set the `class` attribute directly using [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr):

```
$('#foo').attr('class', 'my_class');
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `.attr()` function like so:

```
$('#foo').attr('class', 'my_class');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use that:

```
$('#foo').attr('class', 'my_class');
```

It will replace any class with "my_class"

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#foo').removeClass().addClass('my_class');
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, found the answer just seconds after I posted the question. Apparently my Google skills were insufficient... :-(

At any rate, the answer is in the removeClass() function. So, you can do:

```
$('#foo').removeClass().addClass("my_class");
```

Couldn't be simpler.

Comment: Wow, you people are fast: While I typed out my own answer, several ones of you answered already! Thank you!

Comment: How is using `attr()` not simpler? It's only a single method call as opposed to two separate calls.

Comment: attr() is simpler and probably faster but I have no benchmarks at hand.

Answer (score -1):

you can try using [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Comment: Nope, if you don't know the name of the current class, it won't help.